# Javascript NaN number not function

Tags: javascript, nan

```
function validNumber(num) {
 field=num.value;
 if(isNaN(field)) {
  alert("The number entered is not a valid number");
  return false;
 } else return true;
}

blur1 = document.getElementById("num1");
blur1.addEventListener("blur",getNumber1,false);
function getNumber1() {
    myNumbers[0] = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    validNumber(myNumbers[0]);
}
```

When I deselect the textbox "num1", it alerts `The number entered is not a valid number` although I inputted a number. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a number to your "validNumber" function. The function expects there to be a "value" property on an object reference passed to it, but since you passed it a number that'll just be `undefined`.

Comment: got it, tq very much!!

Answer (score 1):

'num' in your validNumber function doesn't have a value property, so you need to change

```
field=num.value;
```

to

```
field = num;
```

or better, change the function to

```
function validNumber(num) 
{
   if(isNaN(num)) 
   {
      alert("The number entered is not a valid number");
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Also, you don't need the else clause, as you already `return false` if it is NaN and return true won't be reached if so.

Comment: fixed, tq very much =)